# JavaFX 2 Combo box is not working in win xp

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I am creating a simple javafx standalone application, were i got a combo box to select different items. But unfortunately, when i am testing this application from windows xp, the combo box doesn't seems to be responding to the mouse clicks. It is not showing its dropdown list. However this component is working fine in the Windows 7. I didn't added any custom styles too. Please help me to solve this issue.

Below is the sample code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapp2.SampleController">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="90.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
    <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="120.0" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="69.0" />
    <ComboBox layoutX="126.0" layoutY="49.0">
      <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
          <String fx:value="Item 1" />
          <String fx:value="Item 2" />
          <String fx:value="Item 3" />
        </FXCollections>
      </items>
    </ComboBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Here we have multiple pc's running the same JavaFX2 program, on one it works without issues, on another it doesn't work graphics wise... I'm trying to update the drivers but no success so far. Both are Dell OptiPlex 780's

Answer (score 0):

File a bug against the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Windows XP is twelve years old now and [Microsoft ended mainstream support for it](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/products/lifecycle) over four years ago.  As the bug only seems to occur on Windows XP, fixing it will likely be a pretty low priority unless you have some kind of support contract directly with Oracle.

If Windows XP support is important for your application, I suggest you use a different control type that works well on Windows XP (perhaps a [ChoiceBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/choice-box.htm) or a [ListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm)).

Comment: thanks for giving me the answer. I tried with using ChoiceBox, but it didnt worked out. Although it showed the list, but when i click on an item its graphics gets worse. I had also found that this JavaFX combo box problem appears to only if we click on the item, but we could use the arrow keys to select the item one by one.

Comment: OK, make sure you edit your question to link to the bug reference you created, so that others such as Perneel can track it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update your Windows XP, you must use Service Pack 3 and updated graphics drivers. See this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements/jfxpub-system_requirements.htm

You must have a minimum of Java SE 6 Update 29 or Java SE 7 Update 1 installed on your system. For 64-bit Windows XP, only the 32-bit JDK and 32-bit JavaFX runtime are supported.

If it still doesn't solve your problem, try to use one of the components available from http://jfxtras.org/.

You could also try to apply some different CSS style and see what happens.